# How to earn benefit for bitcoin core developer?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Will there be any benefits if we directly provide core source code development for bitcoin? I like Bitcoin very much and I hope to join this community and at the same time have income to subsidize my family.

Answer (score 6):

Incentives for everyone who contributes:

1. You can be proud of yourself to be a contributor in the full node implementation used by 90% of Bitcoin nodes and one of the [critical C++ open source projects](https://twitter.com/_jonasschnelli_/status/1337351770192961540).
2. One more skill added and you will learn a lot of new things: Bitcoin development
3. If your contribution helps Bitcoin Core and other Bitcoin projects, you might get sponsorship from companies or individuals: https://blog.bitmex.com/who-funds-bitcoin-development/
4. Maybe make new friends. Although you may have disagreements sometimes with other contributors. [*People don't have to be 100% friends to work together on a common goal.*](https://twitter.com/orionwl/status/1394205292552916992)

> I like Bitcoin very much and I hope to join this community and at the same time have income to subsidize my family.

You can work in your free time. We can always manage a few hours per week/month for things that we are passionate about.

Answer (score 1):

There are such jobs:

- https://blockstream.com/careers/
- https://chaincode.com/jobs

these companies work with or around the Bitcoin Core code.

You might also find some companies willing to hire you for introducing backdoors.

Comment: Introducing backdoors?

Comment: @Prayank Isn't it likely for NSA to hire those who know Bitcoin's code well and who can inentionally write use-after-free and buffer-overflow vulnerable code? Especially parsers. Who knows, maybe someone creates a script-address format proposal that needs parsing and unless the Core team writes it in Rust, it would be likely for them to add those backdoors unintentionally.

Comment: _NSA to hire those who know Bitcoin's code well and can introduce vulnerability_ : `POSSIBLE` _needs parsing and unless the Core team writes it in Rust, it would be likely for them to add those backdoors unintentionally_ : `NOT SURE` why C++ will be easier to add backdoor. Also its very difficult to introduce vulnerability in open source code that is reviewed by lot of people before getting merged. I don't think I know enough C++ to review and find all such things but few others may find it and comment/NACK/report.

Comment: @Prayank The same can be said about Linux but it happened https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26887670

Comment: Interesting link. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Both modern C++ and Rust make it easy to write code without buffer overflows or use-after-free bugs. To the best of my knowledge, there has never been any of those in the Bitcoin/Bitcoin Core source code (excluding dependencies like miniupnpc). I think focusing on those when being concerned about intentional damage are a distraction.